# Pdf-file download link doesn't work on iphone browsers

Tags: magento2, iphone

I have a page with **Print** button. PDF-file should be downloaded by clicking on it.
It works on all devices except iphone. Downloading link is generated correctly. But when I try to follow it, Chrome on iphone shows `err_failed` and Safari shows empty page.

Controller fragment:

```
<?php
$this->fileFactory->create(
   $filename,
  [
    'type' => 'string',
    'value' => file_get_contents($file),
    'rm' => true
  ],
  DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
  'application/pdf'
);
```

**Print** button:

```
<a href="{link for downloading}" target="_self">Print</a>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: download or view pdf ?

Comment: To download pdf.